# Unable to load schema from 'https://json.schemastore.org/package': getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND json.schemastore.org."

Tags: nodejs-server

Unable to load schema from 'https://json.schemastore.org/package': getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND json.schemastore.org."

Unable to load schema from 'https://json.schemastore.org/package': getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND json.schemastore.org."